# Basis set in the computational software "Gaussian-03" for studying adsorption of a hydrogen atom on a carbon paste electrode dropcasted with Pt-CNT

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry, computational-chemistry, surface-chemistry, catalysis

What is the basis set in the computational software "Gaussian-03" that can be used to study the interaction of $\ce{H}$-atom with $\ce{Pt-CNT}$ dropcasted electrode? How can we study the energy differences that arises due to the interaction computationally?

Comment: Maybe you want to share how far you got so far with your literature search and considering different calculations methods and models for your system. Why did you choose this or that calculation method and such detail... The question in this form would suggest you have very little idea about what you want to do.

Comment: I agree with @Greg. I also do think, that Gaussian is usually not the right program to do calculations for surface chemistry. Also, 03 is quite old now and might perform very weakly for large systems.

Comment: Actually this is a part of our groups work in regard to electrocatalysis. We just wanted to support our findings computationally by studying the interactions between the chemical moiety and the modified electrode

Comment: then you could at least a little bit information about your system here.
I go with Greg it.